# What are the exact circumstances for Common Subexpression Elimination (CSE) to occur in GHC?

Tags: haskell, optimization, compiler-construction, ghc

I have found that Haskell is able to perform CSE if some circumstances are met. I was reading this article: https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC_optimisations, but I didn't find any specific information and was redirected to GHC's manual, which told me only how to enable it and dump log of this optimizer.

I would like to determine whether my code will be able to perform it or not. Where can I find this kind of documentation? Is it published anywhere?

Comment: If you have some formula which is repeated in your code, best is to give it a name then use the name. Declare with a `let` or `where`. Do you have some code that seems a memory hog or is running slowly and you think there's an opportunity for CSE that GHC is not taking? Then please show the code. (Because often people think their code has opportunities, but they're not considering that it might be polymorphic.) Otherwise your q is just too broad.

Comment: Well, it's certainly published in the source code of GHC at the very least...